# Why was my question about an Electron app's URL deleted automatically by Community?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Why was my question ([How can we fake an Electron app's URL (window.location)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940665/how-can-we-fake-an-electron-apps-url-window-location)
) deleted?

In my opinion, it is a valid question. Seems like it was deleted because people don't like what I'm trying to do? Seems like personal like/dislike shouldn't be a factor for closing questions.

Comment: Post a screenshot for non-10k users

Comment: The banner under the question tells you precisely why it was deleted, and even links to a page with further information if you want more details.

Comment: It was deleted by the Roomba, so there was definitely not personal like/dislike

Comment: 18K rep and you didn't put a bounty on it.  What are you saving it for?

Comment: "Seems like it was deleted because people don't like what I'm trying to do?" ... funny to see how fast people are in creating conspiracy theories and a "me against the world" mentality.

Comment: @Tom I'm not yet familiar with the moderator features I get at this level of reputation. I just correlated the downvotes with the deletion. Do the downvotes not have any impact on triggering deletion?

Comment: @DavisBroda screenshot posted in Makoto's answer

Comment: @trusktr You can read the information in the deletion banner to find the answer to that question.

Comment: On "triggering" deletion only by alluring people to look why it has that many downvotes and they _may_ cast a delete vote when they have the needed reputation points. But other than that? No. Roomba also looks at the post score, but that is just one indicator and the score allow isn't enough for Roomba to delete a question.

Comment: @Tom What should I do, to ask the same valid question?

Comment: Like Hans suggested: a bounty. Your question got deleted because no-one wrote any comments/answers for a long time, but a bounty can attract more people and increase the chance to find someone who can answer it.

Comment: No, ask a *better* question. A moderator could undelete that one for you, but I don't see what the point would be.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to ask a better question. I mean, honestly the question describes exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 17):

It was deleted by the system.  You have enough reputation to see this for yourself.

The system has no opinion of your question, but it *did* meet the criteria for [automatic deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).  Let's not make what is an automated process any more empathetic than it is capable of being.

[image]

Comment: As they're the author, they'd be able to see it regardless of how much reputation they have.